# Wait until 'for loop' or 'push' is complete then run function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, push

Hi i'm using the following code. I need some way for the script to wait until clickButton() is finished before running initialize(). Or maybe waiting until push is completed? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
 $("#getButtonValue").click(clickButton);
 function clickButton() {
    for( i = 1; i < counter; i++){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $('#textbox' + i).val()
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        latCoords.push(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                        longCoords.push(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            } 
        }); 
    }
    initialize();
 }
```

Comment: Geocoder.geocode is a promise?

Comment: i'm not that familiar with javascript. I'm just trying to link two separate functions. I need one to wait for the other and am not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Is initialize being called ahead of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you're trying to do.

Without using promise, a simple workaround would be to create a counter to see if all geocoder.geocode() calls are completed.

```
$("#getButtonValue").click(clickButton);
function clickButton() {
    // A counter variable
    int completeCount = 0; 
    for( i = 1; i < counter; i++){
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = $('#textbox' + i).val()
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                latCoords.push(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                longCoords.push(results[0].geometry.location.lng());

                // Increment completeCount
                completeCount++; 

                // If all geocoder.geocode() calls received an "OK", initialize()
                if (completeCount == counter) {
                    initialize();
                }
            } 
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers mate it worked perfect. I just started with javascript and it a little confusing to me the way it bahaves

Comment: @user2441222 really recommend you reading this https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript

Comment: @user2441222 Once you understand the event loop in javascript, everything will make much more sense.